# running one job with multiple trigger

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have (N) trigger but one running job at a time.
I want to control the trigger that misfired and after job finished run the most recent misfired trigger.
Is there any solution with Quartz.net available ?

**Edit:** I want to have a dictionary like structure for all triggers and if one of them misfired update last misfired time of that trigger then after completing the running job decide which trigger should run if it is passed smaller than 40% of its misfired time.
(trigger checking is based on priority)

Comment: Can you give us some more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand completely your question, but I guess your solution is create a structure that is handled by listeners.
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_7.html

in example ( IJobListener )

```
public void JobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    ...deal with triggers, and determine the last one;
}

public void JobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
    ...now with the job complete you can fire another behavior.
}
```